# Passing a function in functional react

Tags: reactjs, forms, function

This code works:

StateForm

```
const StateForm = () => {

const [form, setState] = useState({});

const setFormValue = e => {
    setState({
        ...form,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
}

return <ActualForm setFormValue={setFormValue} entries={form} />
```

ActualForm

```
    const ActualForm = ({setFormValue, entries}) => {
    return (
...
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" value={entries?.email} onChange={setFormValue} />
... }
```

But this does not and I cannot figure out why:

```
    const StateForm = () => {

    const [form, setState] = useState({});

    const setFormValue = (name, value) => {
        setState({
            ...form,
            [name]: value
        });

    return <ActualForm setFormValue={setFormValue} entries={form} />

}
```

Actual Form

```
const ActualForm = ({setFormValue, entries}) => {
        return (
    ...
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value={entries?.email} onChange={e => setFormValue('email', e.target.value)} />
    ... }
```

I need this second version to work due to a third party component I am utilizing.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What doesn't work "exactly" ?

Comment: `setFormValue` has no closing brace in the second example

Comment: @azium - the error I get is "TypeError: setFormValue is not a function"

Comment: @Matt - sorry, my actual jsx does not have the open bracket before the e

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a brecate here, you did not close off `setFormValue`:

```
 const StateForm = () => {

const [form, setState] = useState({});

const setFormValue = (name, value) => {
    setState({
        ...form,
        [name]: value
    });

}
return <ActualForm setFormValue={setFormValue} entries={form} />

}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was bad copying and pasting.  It was actually closed in my code.

Comment: Why are you returning `ActuelForm` in `setFormValue`? What is that supposed to do?

Comment: Ors - separate the from appearance from its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I created a snippet of your code. There is not any errors. so tell us more about your problem.

```js
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;


const StateForm = () => {
  const [form, setState] = useState({});
  const setFormValue = (name, value) => {
      setState({
          ...form,
          [name]: value
      });
  }
  return <ActualForm setFormValue={setFormValue} entries={form} />
}

const ActualForm = ({setFormValue, entries}) => {
  return (
    <input 
      id="email" 
      name="email"
      type="email"
      value={entries?.email}
      onChange={
        e => setFormValue('email', e.target.value)
      }
    />
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<StateForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: The error I get is "TypeError: setFormValue is not a function"